# Registering external users through Azure SSO (in Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I've been searching everywhere, but can't seem to find anything on specifically registering users through Azure.

Primary question: how does one configure Azure to allow users to register themselves to an Azure Active Directory through SSO?

Secondary: how to do so with SSO on WordPress

Explanation: I use Azure AD to manage app registration, I want users to have a login without buying (purchase workflow invites them to the AD and assigns them a group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD manages authentication and authorisation.

It does not manage provisioning.

This is done manually via the portal, programmatically via Graph API, via AAD Connect from on-premises or by using SCIM.

For external users, Azure AD provides [external identities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/#overview) where the user can self-register,

Comment: External identities seem to be what I've been looking for. The only problem is that users that aren't external (school email e.g.) still can't self-register

Answer (score 0):

User cannot register themselves in Azure AD by their own. Only Admin Have a privileged to add and remove user from Azure Active Directory.
Admin and user who has privileged to invites them to the AD and assigns them a group.

WordPress Login with Azure (Azure SSO) plugin allows you Login(Single Sign-On) to your WordPress site using your Azure(Azure AD / Azure B2C / Office 365 ) account credentials. This plugin uses OAuth/OpenID Connect protocol to achieve Single Sign-on.This plugin also provides SSO with custom applications as well.

> This Azure SSO plugin allows all Azure users (Active Directory Users,
> B2C Users,and `external users`) to login into WordPress with their
> existing Microsoft Azure account and also create a user account into
> WordPress. Some of the Azure Single Sign-On use-cases are listed
> below.
>
> - Single Sign-On to WordPress using Azure AD users (Azure AD SSO)
> - Single Sign-On to WordPress using Azure B2C users (Azure B2C SSO)
> - Single Sign-On to WordPress using external users synced to Azure AD (Azure AD SSO)
> - Single Sign-On to WordPress using Office 365 users (Office 365 SSO)

Please refer this [document1](https://plugins.miniorange.com/saml-single-sign-on-sso-wordpress-using-azure-ad) and [Document2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-azure/) to implement Registering external users through Azure SSO (in Wordpress)

Comment: Well, I've already seen that link, and it's the reverse of what I am searching for. I am looking for a plugin that interacts with the Graph API to register users into Azure.